# sass file not compiling to css with gulp sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

my directory file is

```
css
  --nothing yet
sass
  --style.sccs
Gulpfile.js
index.html
package.json
```

here is my Gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var sassOptions = {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'expanded'
};

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  return gulp
    // Watch the input folder for change,
    // and run `sass` task when something happens
    .watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass'])
    // When there is a change,
    // log a message in the console
    .on('change', function(event) {
      console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch' ]);
```

here is style.sccs

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

when I run gulp from the terminal it looks ok

```
PS C:\Users\delli\gulpsass> gulp
[21:02:08] Using gulpfile ~\gulpsass\gulpfile.js
[21:02:08] Starting 'sass'...
[21:02:08] Starting 'watch'...
[21:02:08] Finished 'watch' after 12 ms
[21:02:08] Finished 'sass' after 41 ms
[21:02:08] Starting 'default'...
[21:02:08] Finished 'default' after 43 μs
```

however my css folder is always empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a typo.

Your file should be `style.scss`, not `style.sccs`.